# Promise Rejected Uncaught Data was empty

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, polymer

I am making a web app With Polymer. I make a POST request and then fill an object, then I'm making a databind to fill the `data` attribute needed in the google-chart tag I'm using.

```
<dom-module id="leads-chart" bind>
  <template>
    <google-chart
      id="leadschart"
            type='column'   
            data={{datagraph}}>
        </google-chart>   
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({ is: "leads-chart",
  properties:{
    params:{
      type: Object
    },
    command:{
      type: String,
      value: "SP_GetLead12Meses"
    },
    datagraph:{
      type: Object,
      computed: 'getBargraph(command,params)'
    }
  },
  getBargraph: function(command,params){

      var options = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        path: '/',
        port: 8081,
        secure: false,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'x-powered-by': 'HTTPClient.js'
        },
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }

    var dictionary = new Object();

    var outter = [];

    const that = this;

    var example1 = new HTTPClient(options)
      example1.post("/executeGraph1?command="+ command + "&param1=" + params.user, function (err, res, body) {

        body = JSON.parse(body);

        outter.push(['Mes','Leads',{"role":"style"}]);

        for(var k in body){
          var inner = [];
          inner.push(dictionary[body[k]['MES']]);
          inner.push(body[k]['LEADS']);
          inner.push("#00A6d4");
          outter.push(inner);
        }
      });

      return outter;
  }
});
```

The problem is the chart is not showing any data. The browser  shows the following message:

[image: Uncaught (in promise) Data was empty]

The weirdest thing is that this error at the beggining was present in rare ocations but now I get it every time I load the page. Does someone know why is it happening and how to solve it?

- I have made some debugging and found out the post message is answering the request with the correct information.

  - the object is being filled with data but the message is still there and chart is still empty

Comment: Your `return outter;` returns an empty array, since the response callback function is called at a later time. You should refactor your code so that you set a property on the custom element when the request finishes and let Polymer data binding to the magic.

Comment: @alesc You are completely right. I wish i could mark your comment as answer. thanks